# how do I undo another developers git push to the master branch

Tags: git, push, git-merge, git-commit

This seems like it would happen all the time, but i can't find an answer.

**what happened:**

Another developer has **git merge**d a branch with the master branch on their local server resulting in **conflicts**. Then **git add**ed the conflicts, **git commit**ted, and **git push**ed the changes & conflicts to the master branch. Dropped his mic and left the building :

**the question:**

is there a way for me to undo this last conflicted commit, so i can push my code changes to master and continue my day, leaving the other developer to fix the conflicted code on his local machine???

---

**what i've found so far:**

I've already committed my local changes and pulled the 'conflicted commit' to my local server...

the two options I'm finding are:

option 1:

```
git revert -m 1 <conflicted commit>
```

This will undo all of the changes made by the conflicted commit. but when the other developer does a git pull all their changes will be deleted. right?

option 2:

```
git reset --hard <my commit>;
git push --force;
```

this will completely remove the conflicted commit from git as if it never happened (which i don't love). But now the other developers local server will be out of sync.

what would you do?

Comment: Are these conflicts actively causing pain; that is, are they causing test failures, or regressions in behavior?  Git will tell you if there were conflicts when merging, but so long as they were resolved well then there wouldn't normally be a problem.

Comment: I'd do option 2.  But the conflicted commit will not be totally removed.  It is in the other developers, origin/master, (until pull/fetch) and in the reflogs (yours, his, server).

Comment: You are correct about first option. Other developers changes will be removed if you do revert. Option 2 is the way to go. On his machine, his local will be ahead with his commits made from server. If he takes pull again, the changes will be merged again causing conflict like earlier which he needs to resolve again.

Comment: @makoto site is borked.

Comment: @Vishwanath Thank you I've gone with option 2. first time I've done that. hopefully the other developer don't need too much help to get back on track.

Answer (score 3):

If it's only one commit that you want to undo, the safest way to fix is your first option:

`git revert -m 1 <conflicted commit>`

In general, it's dangerous to use `git reset` on any commit that is on the remote repository. If anyone has cloned the repository since those changes have been pushed and made their own changes, they will run into trouble when they try to sync with `git pull`. There's an 'orphaned commit' with a 'dangling head'. While both of these things can be worked around with time, there's no reason to get into this type of trouble if it can be fixed with a simple `git revert`.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the simplest solution here is the best - especially if no other changes have been made. Simply doing a `git checkout` for the commit before his push and re-committing those files will still leave the other developer with the history of what was done, while resolving the issues you have with the conflicted state. One downside of this approach, however, is that it does leave conflicted/non-compiling code in your repository.

Comment: @tcmarch thank you, what would be the different between git checkout and git revert in this scenario? is it basically the same except new files won't be deleted?

Comment: `checkout` as opposed to `revert` is about what changes are maintained. `revert` will remove changes from the selected commit, while `checkout` would get the repository state at the selected commit. In your case, with the fact that only one change was committed between where you wanted your `HEAD` to be and the bad code, `checkout` (being familiar to you) was a very viable option. `revert` is probably most often going to be a better option, though, unless you're often removing the most recent change to the server version of the repository. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to improve your work flow. It's not good and safe to allow every one to update the main branches in the server. Besides, `git push --force` is too dangerous, which you should never use on any public branch in a team work. You could allow any push to a non-main branch. A code-review team reviews the changes and merges the commits into main branches by `git merge`,`git cherry-pick`, `git rebase`, `git apply`, `git am` and etc. Once a commit is made onto the main branch, only use `git revert` to undo it. Developers could use `git pull --rebase` to sync the local changes with the latest main branch if necessary. Also they can `git fetch` the main branch and organize their own commits onto it.